# Multiple Account Set up

Tags: administration, account, account-management

We have multiple business units in our Org and the existing setup is set in a way by consultants that every account in Salesforce will have a unique Business Unit.

For Example

Business Unit XYZ will have a new  Account ABC
and 
Business Unit MNO alsowill have a new Account ABC.

Can you all suggest if this is the best practice for Account Management in a long run.

However If I need to see data related to a account I will have to check all the Business Unit accounts for Information.

Please Suggest Ideas

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This is a difficult question to answer without knowing your sales process/account process. I'd guess that if you had consultants, then they would've done what they thought was best. I'd consider adding more info in an [edit] about why you think this might not be the best setup

Comment: Thank you Kris! I have sorted this out and this was done because of Duplicate Management.